# How to construct an array of objects by using the keys of another array of objects and values from the array of arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have two arrays as listed below. I'm trying to create a new array of objects by using the `field` key in array_1 and the values in array_2.

```
const result = []
array_1 = [{ name: "Color" , field: "color"}, {name: "Shape", field: "shape" }, { name: "Whatever", field: "whatever" }]

array_2 = [["green", "rectangular", "whatever1"], ["yellow", "circle", "whatever2"]]
```

The result should be:

```
console.log(result)
// [{color:"green", shape:"rectangular", whatever: "whatever1"}, 
//  { color:"yellow", shape: "circle", whatever:"whatever2"}]
```

I did this at my final trial:

```
const rowObj = {}
const result = array.map((subarray) => subarray.map((cell, index) => {
      console.log(cell,index)
      rowObj[columns[index].field] = cell
      return rowObj
    }))
```

Basically, I was overwriting the same object.

Thanks,

Comment: You tried doing it yourself?

Comment: Yes, I did. My result was [ [{}] , [{}] ].

Comment: Please include that code in your question.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to `map()` over the `array_2` and in each iteration:

1. Create a new object
2. Iterate over the `array_1` to fill the newly created object. You can use the index parameter of the `forEach()` method's callback function to get the `field` property from the objects inside `array_1`.

and then return that object from the callback function of the `map()` method.

```js
const array_1 = [
  { name: 'Color', field: 'color' },
  { name: 'Shape', field: 'shape' },
  { name: 'Whatever', field: 'whatever' },
];

const array_2 = [
  ['green', 'rectangular', 'whatever1'],
  ['yellow', 'circle', 'whatever2'],
];

const result = array_2.map(arr => {
  const o = {};

  arr.forEach((str, idx) => {
    o[array_1[idx].field] = str;
  });
  
  return o;
}); 

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate both arrays and take advantage of [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to build new objects based on the order of array elements:

```js
array_1 = [{ name: "Color" , field: "color"}, {name: "Shape", field: "shape" }, { name: "Whatever", field: "whatever" }]

array_2 = [["green", "rectangular", "whatever1"], ["yellow", "circle", "whatever2"]]

let result = array_2.map(
      x => Object.fromEntries(
        array_1.map((y,i) => ([y.field, x[i]]))))

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

## Explanation

You could create a function that creates a constructor based on the descriptions of your object's fields like this:

```js
function createConstructor(fieldsDescriptor) {
  return function(fields) {
    fieldsDescriptor.forEach((descriptor, index) => {
      this[descriptor.field] = fields[index]
    })
  }
}
```

Then you could, for example, make a sampleConstructor that creates objects based on the field names of array_1:

```
const SampleConstructor = createConstructor(array_1)
```

And then, for each entry in array_2 you could apply your SampleConstructor:

```
const result = array_2.map(fields => new SampleConstructor(fields))
```

## Motivation

Creating a dedicated constructor adds some clear semantics to your app, shows readers what you are doing and also stores constructor information in the created objects at runtime.

When you later want to know which constructor made which objects you can just call `object.constructor` and use this information to determine what kind of objects they are.

For example calling `result[0].constructor == SampleConstructor` will be true because SampleConstructor is the constructor that created the first result.

## Demo

Here is a full demo

```js
const array_1 = [{ name: "Color" , field: "color"}, {name: "Shape", field: "shape" }, { name: "Whatever", field: "whatever" }]
const array_2 = [["green", "rectangular", "whatever1"], ["yellow", "circle", "whatever2"]]

function createConstructor(fieldsDescriptor) {
  return function(fields) {
    fieldsDescriptor.forEach((descriptor, index) => {
      this[descriptor.field] = fields[index]
    })
  }
}

const SampleConstructor = createConstructor(array_1)
const results = array_2.map(fields => new SampleConstructor(fields))
console.log(results)

const EmptyConstructor = createConstructor([])
console.log(results[0].constructor == SampleConstructor)
console.log(results[0].constructor == EmptyConstructor)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
array_1 = [
      { name: 'Color', field: 'color' },
      { name: 'Shape', field: 'shape' },
      { name: 'Whatever', field: 'whatever' }
    ];
    
    array_2 = [
      ['green', 'rectangular', 'whatever1'],
      ['yellow', 'circle', 'whatever2']
    ];
    
    const keys = array_1.map(item => item.field);
    
    const output = [];
    array_2.forEach(item => {
      const temp = {};
      for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        const key = keys[i];
        const value = item[i];
        temp[key] = value;
      }
      output.push(temp);
    });
    
    console.log(output);
```